# Do I have to use the accelerometer in Android to get my photos to orient correctly?

Tags: android, android-camera, sensors, screen-orientation

I notice that when you take photos with the native camera app, they come out portrait or landscape (as they should), however, when I take photos in my app using the Camera class, they are always landscape, no matter how I'm holding the device.

I'm really hoping I don't have to monitor the orientation of the device and manually rotate the images... is there a less silly way to get this done?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use accelerometer. You can just check the orientation by the time the photo is taken.
[Developer Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation)

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

Comment: hmm... ok, that takes care of knowing how the device is being held, but do I then have to manually reorder the Bitmap data, rotating the image? I was imagining that this is something that the Camera class would tackle without my needing to intervene.  Oh, and I just realized that you're pulling from resources which would only work if I set the orientation manually in the layout, right? Or is this going to give me the live orientation currently experienced by the app at run time?